# Map-reduce JobConf - Error in adding FileInputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have created a `Mapper` using the syntax:

```
public class xyz extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{
    -----
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
        OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
    --
}
```

In the job, I created a Job object:

```
Job job = new Job(getConf());
```

To this job, I am not able to add Mapper class using:

```
job.setMapper(xyz);
```

error message:

```
The method setMapperClass(Class<? extends Mapper>) in the type Job is not applicable for the arguments (Class<InvertedIndMap1>)
```

I cannot use a map with extends `Mapper` as I am using `outputCollector`and `Reporter` in the `mapper`.

In the job, if I use `JobConf` instead of job like:

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf());
```

then `conf.setMapper(xyz)` is working.

But not able to set input paths using:

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(conf,new Path(args[0]));
```

Error message:

```
The method addInputPaths(Job, String) in the type FileInputFormat is not applicable for the arguments (JobConf, Path)
```

I tried `setInputPaths`, `setInputpath`, `addInputPath`. But same error again. 
Same error occurs for `addOutputPath/SetOuputpath`.

Please suggest a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have imported not suitable `FileInputFormat`. I guess that you need to replace

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
```

with

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically mixing the two imports, the mapred(older) and mapreduce(new).Try to include only one and replace all the older with the new mapreduce class